# Running a forEach loop in Mongoose, in reverse

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm currently trying to make a faux blog style page. All the relevant information is in MongoDB and I'm extracting it using a forEach loop.

```
`<% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
   <img src="<%= blog.image %>" >
   <a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id%>"><%=blog.title%></a>
  <span><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
  <p><%- blog.body.substring(0, 100) %>...</p>
   <% }) %>`
```

The database contains these objects when you create/edit a post. When you run a forEach it will start at the beginning of the database and then work forwards. I'm trying to figure out how to make it go in reverse as a typical blog site will push older posts down the page when new content is posted (as of now it's displaying the first post first, second one second, etc.)

I thought about creating a for loop and constraining the length of it by using the .count() mongoose command but I can't seem to figure out how I can relate it the various objects in the database. Basically I'm trying to convert this forEach to use a variable (like [i]).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mongoose . It is a MongoDB object modeling tool designed to work in an asynchronous environment. Mongoose makes it very easy to work with MongoDB. You can try these (some of these may not work properly) , hopefully it will help you.

```
model_name.find({}).sort('-date').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
model_name.find({}).sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
model_name.find({}).sort({date: 'desc'}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
model_name.find({}).sort({date: 'descending'}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
model_name.find({}).sort([['date', -1]]).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
model_name.find({}, null, {sort: '-date'}, function(err, docs) { ... });
model_name.find({}, null, {sort: {date: -1}}, function(err, docs) { ... });
```